# Unknown symbol in lme4 output

Tags: r, lme4

I've fit a linear mixed effects model with the `lme4` package in R. I'm predicting a continuous `outcome` variable with two categorical fixed factors, `direction` (upwards/downwards) and `utility` (positive/neutral/negative), and `Participant` as a random factor. I want to test for the effect of `direction`, `utility`, and an interaction of the two on `outcome`, so I've written a model like so:

`model <- lmer(outcome ~ direction * utility + (1|Participant), data = DF)`

And the output looks like this:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: outcome ~ direction * utility + (1 | Participant)
   Data: DF

REML criterion at convergence: 35381.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5722 -0.5269 -0.2075  0.2518  5.8625 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Participant (Intercept)  5.832   2.415   
 Residual                96.155   9.806   
Number of obs: 4761, groups:  Participant, 100

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                  8.9769     0.3189  28.153
directionUpwards            -6.1652     0.2912 -21.172
utility.L                   -4.1623     0.3577 -11.635
utility.Q                   -3.0612     0.3668  -8.346
directionUpwards:utility.L   4.2283     0.5000   8.456
directionUpwards:utility.Q   3.6176     0.5049   7.165

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) drctnU utlt.L utlt.Q drU:.L
drctnUpwrds -0.473                            
utility.L   -0.068  0.076                     
utility.Q   -0.019  0.019 -0.070              
drctnUpw:.L  0.051  0.008 -0.720  0.049       
drctnUpw:.Q  0.015 -0.020  0.052 -0.720  0.011
```

What does the L and Q attached to `utility` in the output mean? Since they don't correspond to the possible values of `utility`, I'm unsure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not `lme4`-specific.

These terms are the linear (`L`) and quadratic (`Q`) coefficients from an orthogonal polynomial contrast; this happens because `utility` has been defined as an *ordered factor*.  If you had more levels of the factor they would be labeled `C` (cubic), `4`, (quartic/4th-order), `5`, etc.

If you want to go back to the ordinary behaviour of factors (i.e. treatment contrasts) you could convert `utility` back to unordered (`data <- transform(data,utility=factor(utility,ordered=FALSE))`) or use one of the various methods for specifying that you want treatment contrasts.

Answer (score 2):

The `L` and `Q` stand for Linear and Quadratic contrasts. By default, R does treatment contrasts for un-ordered factors and polynomial contrasts for ordered factors.

You can view the R contrasts like this

```
> options('contrasts')
$contrasts
    unordered      ordered
"contr.treatment"   "contr.poly"
```

It sounds like you were expecting treatment contrasts.  You can change R's contrasts for ordered factors like this

```
> options(contrasts=c('contr.treatment','contr.treatment'))
```

Another option is to convert your factors to unordered. For example,

```
DF$direction = factor(DF$direction, ordered = FALSE)
```